# Automating export Azure Devops pipeline Work Items Revisions using Python Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfs-workitem

Currently I am using Azure Devops Pipeline OData Service to export the data using the following link:

```
 https://<CompanyName>.analytics.visualstudio.com/<ProjectName>/_odata/v2.0/WorkItemRevisions?$apply=filter(CreatedDateSK%20eq%20<Date>%20and%20WorkItemType%20eq%20%27<WorkItemType%27)
```

and I am using extraction tool (Talend DI) to automatically change in these parameters, and I am running python code (Selenium Library) to webscrape the above mentioned link using basic authentication.

Is there any other alternative solution other than selenium to do this task.
As selenium web driver gives time out error when waiting for large size oage to be loaded.

```py
try:
        content_element=expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,contentElementID))
        WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(content_element)
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        if(i==14):
                driver.quit()
                raise TimeoutException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Requests HTTP library to call the OData Service. Please check below codes example:

```
import requests
import json
import base64

if __name__ == "__main__":

    pat = 'Personal access token'
    authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')

    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
    }       

    url = "https://<CompanyName>.analytics.visualstudio.com/<ProjectName>/_odata/v2.0/WorkItemRevisions?$apply=filter(CreatedDateSK%20eq%20<Date>%20and%20WorkItemType%20eq%20%27<WorkItemType%27)"

    #you can also use below domain dev.azure.com, which is the new domain of azure devops service
    #url = "https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_odata/v2.0//WorkItems?`$select=WorkItemId,Title,State&`$expand=Parent(`$select=WorkItemId,Title,State)&`$filter=WorkItemId eq 12"

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    print(response.content)
```

Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) to get a Person access token with the right permission scope.